# react native app can't open from background state

Tags: react-native

I have developed an app using React Native.
It not opening, when try to open from recent apps(background state).
This issue is not found in all phone only in some phones like OPPO 13+

Please help someone to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problems. and you should check your device's android version. after android 7.4 you should configure AndroidManifest.xml more something like below

```
 <receiver
    android:name=".AutoRun"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution is working on all other phone except  oneplus nord i don't know why..do you have any idea?

Comment: @whereJERRY this solution is not working do you have any other alternative solution for this issue